# Can not start mining on parity kovan testnet

Tags: parity

I have been setting up node with parity kovan testnet on cloud instance.I want to start mining with ethminer.

When I start mining with:

```
ethminer -C -F "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
```

gives error as:

```
miner  06:39:47.443|ethminer  Getting work package...
JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...
```

And starting with:

```
ethminer -G -F "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
```

gives error as:

```
[OPENCL]:No OpenCL platforms found
No GPU device with sufficient memory was found. Can't GPU mine. Remove the -G argument
```

With geth I can successfully start mining on same cloud instance but can't with parity.

Starting parity with:

```
parity --jsonrpc-port "8545" --jsonrpc-apis "all" --port "30303" --chain=kovan --author (address of coinbase)
```

How could I fix the error I am facing?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before even looking into the miner issues: [Kovan](https://github.com/kovan-testnet/proposal) is a [Proof-of-Authority](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Proof-of-Authority-Chains) network. You can not mine a PoA-network with traditional [PoW](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Proof-of-Work-Chains) miners.

Geth does not support Kovan either, by the way. If you want a testnet that works for both clients and allows PoW mining, have a look at `--chain ropsten`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.Yes you are right.I am running geth with ropsten. So able to mine with geth.